# Проблемы с шаблонами State & Observer

Tags: java, многопоточность, шаблоны-проектирования, асинхронность

Имеется примерная UML диаграмма классов - [ссылка на редактирование](http://www.codeuml.com/?635706843700581209). 
Имеется источник данных, который в отдельном потоке раз в несколько секунд циклом кое-что опрашивает и создаёт набор параметров - класс `Parameters` на диаграмме. Интерфейс `ParameterListener` и источник данных взаимодействуют как паттерн `Observer`. Затем этот источник данных вызывает метод `onChangedParameters(Parameters p);` - асинхронно, в другом потоке. Далее после оповещения слушателя (слушатель реализует `Context`), данные отправляются в `State` для принятия решения об изменении текущего `Состояния` объекта.

У класса `Context` кроме оповещнеия, есть метод `userPressedStart(Settings s);`.  Этот метод вызывается юзером и это запрос на запуск. Сюда передается набор настроек - `Settings`.

**Суть проблемы:**

Дело в том, что система может запуститься только если у неё правильные Параметры - `Parameters`. А Параметры приходят асинхронно (метод `onChangedParameters(Parameters p)`) и независимо от запроса юзера на запуск (метод  `userPressedStart(Settings s)`). Есть вариант добавить в класс `Context` поле `private volatile Parameters params;` и при срабатывании метода события обновлять поле, А в момент нажатии юзером кнопки `Start`, делать проверку этого поля... Как лучше всего сделать это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Боюсь, я не до конца понял вопрос. Если требуется подтянуть параметры при пользовательском инпуте, то пусть источник параметров тоже слушает события, и делает запрос, как только слышит событие, и пока он не отработал, у пользователя крутится спиннер. Если это ожидание совсем критично, то пусть при запуске приложения источник парамтеров сразу же их запрашивает.

Comment: т.е. во время юзерского нажатия на `start` принудительно сделать запрос на получение `Parameters` ? Звучит неплохо, но источник данных спроектирован таким образом, что он может и не ответить. И это не будет считаться критической ошибкой.

Comment: Так и написать юзеру - ответ не был получен, пробуем еще.

Comment: Спасибо за коммент. Завтра попробую реализовать этого монстра.

Answer (score 2):

Ну давайте посмотрим. Во-первых, у вас есть параметры. Я бы поддерживал их в правильном состоянии вне зависимости от того, запустил юзер процесс или нет. То есть нам нужно начиная от старта программы слушать изменение параметров, и иметь отдельный флаг о том, пришли ли параметры на самом деле. (Или если параметры не могут быть `null`, то флаг не нужен.)

Окей, теперь что происходит, если юзер нажал старт? Если параметры уже есть, стартуем с этими параметрами. Если нет, выводим ему «жди, параметров пока нету», и отдельно подписываемся на изменение параметров. Выводим юзеру кнопку «надоело ждать». При приходе параметров убираем всё, отписываемся от изменений и выполняем. При нажатии кнопки «надоело» отписываемся от изменений и выходим.

Comment: спасибо. я решил эту проблему добавлением нового состояния - `ready`.